# Multiple users to one schema. how to get them to see each other sql scripts

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, database-administration

I've been grinding out this issue and I can't seem to find anything on this particular thing.

So I have a "group Schema" to which I have multiple users assigned to. What I would like to do is have them see each other SQL scripts that they saved.

I've gone through the users and groups settings and tinkered around as well as gone through the documentation, but I don't really see anything regarding the subject.

The roundabout way that I see at the moment is having them use the Team development section and using that, however that doesn't seem effective. Any ideas or thoughts on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Basically SQL scripts are not stored in the data base. To be stored the *script* would have to be a procedure, function, or package.  You could of course write the script into a table column and have users reference that table, but that of course is not simple. Team development is not a roundabout - it is a proper way of accomplishing this.